# How can I simplify this switch statement?

Tags: javascript

For some reason, I have to offset my top, left position for a div. I have started to create this switch statement and have noticed a pattern, when greater than three increment the value by a number, then increment then next value by the last offset - .11. How can I simplify this code, perhaps creating a formula or something instead of the many case statements?

Here's my code:

matte_width_value is the value of a select statement;

```
    switch (matte_width_value)
    {
      case 2.25:
        offset = -.4;
        break;
      case 2.5:
        offset = -.7;
        break;
      case 2.75:
        offset = -1.1;
        break;
      case 3.25:
        offset = 1.35;
        break;
      case 3.5:
        offset = 1.24;
        break;
      case 3.75:
        offset = 1.12;
        break;
      case 4:
        offset = 1.01;
        break;
      //The cases will increment by .25 until it reaches <6
    }
    x = (matte_width_value + offset) * ppi; //ppi is defined elsewhere
    y = (matte_width_value + offset) * ppi;
```

Here's an image of what is happening (note the light gray rectangle should be directly centered and covering the dark rectangle, the dark rectangle isn't a div, it's the background color for a div):

[image]

Here is the html markup:

```
<div id="mattes" style="width: 247.5px; height: 292.5px; left: 201.25px; top: 23.75px;">
  <div id="opening_0" style="background-color: #bfbfbf; position: absolute; left: 63.75px; top: 63.75px; height: 138.75px; width: 93.75px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 4;" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" onclick="photos_add_selected_fid(this);">&nbsp;</div>
  <canvas id="matte_canvas" width="247" height="292" style="z-index: 3;  "></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: your ultimate solution is to figure out why you have to do this at all. My guess is there is something wrong with your CSS and this is a work around.

Comment: *For some reason, I have to offset my top, left position for a div.* -- you have to offset it or else what? Can you explain what offsetting it accomplishes?

Comment: Or else it is not centered. I'll add an image to show you what I am talking about and include the actual html markup.

Comment: @AllisonC: this sounds like an issue with styles which should most likely not be tackled programmatically. This could haunt you forever otherwise as soon as the original CSS changes again, drawing you into a never ending cycle of CSS update --> change code --> CSS update --> change code --> etc..

Comment: @AllisonC where are the values for the width/height/left/top of `mattes` coming from? Are they generated from server-side code, or literal values?

Comment: @DaggNabbit They are generated with javascript with the following code: $("#mattes").append("<div id='opening_" + i + "' style='background-color: #bfbfbf; position: absolute; left: " + x + "px; top: " + y + "px; height: " + opening_height + "px; width: " + opening_width + "px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 4;" + ellipse + "'  ondrop='drop(event, this)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' onclick='photos_add_selected_fid(this);'>&nbsp;</div>");

Comment: @AllisonC is there more CSS in a stylesheet? `left` and `top` aren't doing anything without `position`.

Comment: @DaggNabbit there is a position set in the code right above your comment: ...position: absolute; left: " + x + "px; top: " + y...

Comment: @AllisonC that position belongs to the div appended to #mattes and not to #mattes itself, no? Anyway, if I were you I'd forget about the switch thing, take a step back, and try to reformulate this as a question about the overall approach... this code is pretty hairy. You might find that while you're writing a question about the overall approach, you notice something you missed before.

Comment: Unless matte_width_value is the exact case value it won't execute the code inside the case. So a matte_width_value of 2.76 won't set offset to -1.1 (im guessing that is what you want) If so use `switch(true)` and put case statements as `matte_width_value < 2.75:`

Comment: @Shanimal - the values will always be one of those numbers

Comment: I realize I missed one little detail "The cases will increment by .25 until it reaches <6" Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a case for a lookup-table. Like

```
var mapping = {
    '2.25':  -.4,
    '2.5':   -.7,
    // and so forth
};

offset = mapping[ matte_width_value ];
```

That is just a solution for the original question (= simplifying). There might be a better solution for the actual problem.

Comment: If this isn't likely the best solution to the OP's actual problem, wouldn't it be better as a comment with a link to one of the other thousands of switch -> lookup table answers here?

Answer (score 0):

```
matte_width_value = 4;    
if (matte_width_value > 3) {  
    offset =1.35 - (((matte_width_value - 3.25) / .25) * .11);   
} else {  
    switch (matte_width_value)  
    {
        case 2.25:   
            offset = -.4;  
            break;   
        case 2.5:  
            offset = -.7;
            break;  
        case 2.75:  
            offset = -1.1;  
            break;  
    }  
}  
document.write(offset);
```

Comment: You can write some explanation. will be helpful for readers.. :)